# Is there any solution to use only 1 findViewById in different methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 2 different methods.

Method a will display textview1.
Method b will also display textview1.

In both the methods, I need to include findViewById(R.id.textview1). Thus need to put twice findViewById in the code.

Comment: used data binding or kotlin no need to findviewbyId.

Comment: Use data Binding or findViewById as global variable, i.e not inside the function.

Comment: yes make it as global.thanks @eLi

Comment: you actually don't need to do it twice. Just do `findViewById()` into a class field in onCreate, and use the variable

Comment: But data binding is the best option @MuhammadZawawi good luck

Comment: Can you post your code as well. It will be more easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Use [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library:

```
class Activity {
    @BindView(R.id.textview1)
    TextView view1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
```

You can now access `view1` in any methods in this activity.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use butterknife library.?

Comment: it is simpler to use

Comment: i think data binding is more prefer.https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/say-goodbye-to-findviewbyid-with-data-binding-library/en

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your textview as global variable. 
Then you can use that variable anywhere in that activity or class or fragment.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private TextView textView1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
      textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
   }
   private void method1(){
      textView1.setText("method 1");
   }
   private void method2(){
      textView1.setText("method 2");
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a little correction here Java has no "global variable", the `textView1` here is called member variable or instance variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

ButterKnife is developed by Jake Wharton at Square and is essentially used to save typing repetitive lines of code like findViewById(R.id.view) when dealing with views, thus making our code look a lot cleaner.

add this dependency into your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
```

write this on onCreate()

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

and than you can find you elements like this :

```
@Bind(R.id.txtview1)
Textview textview;
```

Answer (score 0):

// if you are using Kotlin, apply this plugin with the kotlin library in your app Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

// then you can just give the name of the view in the XML layout and you dont have to initialize the view eg ..

// xml view

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="8dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"

                        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

// now in the kotlin class

```
tv_location.text = "Kolkata,India" 

//try this
```